# Multiple image upload using nested forms in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am working on a project where a devise user uploads many images. So what I'm what trying to achieve is the user uploads an image with a description and then can click on a button "add another" which allows the user to add another image and description, the user can add as many images as they want.

Can someone point me in the right direction in what I'm supposed to look into to achieve the task?

Comment: Start with something more basic related to rails and work from there. [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/) is a good resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), the standard functionality for including *nested* attributes in a submission:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Whilst - strictly speaking - the functionality you want is to add multiple elements to a submission (`images#new`), Rails can only deal with one record creation at a time. Using the following will be far more beneficial:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :projects #-> url.com/projects/:id/edit

#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

   def new
      @project = Project.new
      @project.images.build
   end

   def edit
      @project = Project.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @project = Project.find params[:id]
      @project.update project_params
   end

   private

   def project_params
     params.require(:project).permit(:x, :y, images_attributes: [:attachment])
   end
end

#app/views/projects/new.html.erb
<%= render "form", locals: { project: @project } %>

#app/views/projects/edit.html.erb
<%= render "form", locals: { project: @project } %>

#app/views/projects/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for project do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :x %>
   <%= f.text_field :y %>
   <%= f.fields_for :images do |i| %>
      <% if i.object.new_record? %>
        <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
      <% else %>
        <%= image_tag i.object.attachment.url %>
        <%= i.check_box :_destroy %>          
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above should give you a form for a `@project`, with embedded images inside.

---

To add "extra" fields, you'll be best looking at the [`cocoon` gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) or this Railscast: [Nested Forms part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: i started to incorporate this into my project and it seems to be going well, expect, I'm using the wicked gem to make a multipage login, where after entering register details, users enter more details about them selfs, but with rails 4, we have strong parameters, and the cocoon gem passes different parameters like model_attributes: [:id, :Name, :mname, :name, :done, :_destroy], which errors out when passed into the wicked_controller.rb, i posted a question about this on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270729/wicked-gem-with-cocoon-gem-and-devise-user-model

Comment: Let me take a look, I've not used the wicked gem before so I might have to do some reading

Comment: your link to Nested Forms Part 1 goes to the Daily Caller. Some news article

Comment: Not sure why that happened - it was a link to Railscasts originally.